# How i can delete a java session attribute value from a javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

I have a variable, that sends from java to jsp page :

```
String message = "Some message";
request.getSession().setAttribute("message", message);
```

this variable, I create to display messages from the server on the client side using the following code in javaScript:

```
var msg = "${message}";
if (msg != "") {
  $("#modalAdd").show();
}
```

I need to delete this variable or its value through js, since output message, I check whether it has any value, and in this time it's always show's message because after displaying the message, i can't erase value of variable.

Comment: `$(yourElement).attr('message','');`

Comment: JavaScript can not change the variable from the server. That would require an Ajax call/form submission You will need to submit something to the server and have the Java code remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing attribute with jstl code.
I insert into div c:remove tag with javascript after showing the message and it's solve my problem.

```
var msg = "${message}";
    if(msg != ""){$("#modalAdd").show();
    document.getElementById('modal-message').innerHTML ='<c:remove var="message" scope="session" /> ';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as previous reply, for a .jsp, in my layout / template page :

```
<c:if test="${sessionerror!=null}">
    <div class="alert-${sessionerror.level}">
        <spring:message code="${sessionerror.text}"/>
    </div>
</c:if>
<%
// Removing after display
session.removeAttribute("sessionerror");
%>
```

**Edit :**
If you want to transfer your message accross a redirect, you can downgrade your message from Session scope to Request in a Interceptor. It's a "redirect attributes" home made.

Example with a Spring HandlerInterceptor :

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("alert") != null) {
        request.setAttribute("alert", request.getSession().getAttribute("alert"));
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("alert");
    }
}
```